# extjs4 combo box drop down loading image wont go away

Tags: combobox, extjs4

I have the following static store for now.
Everything works fine when i click on the drop down it gives me a loading image and does not go away.

```
var active_store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
storeId: 'active',
model: 'Active',
 data : [
     {active: 'Y'},
     {active: 'N'}
 ],
autoLoad: true
})

{
xtype: 'container',
layout: 'hbox',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        editable:false,
        id:'active',
        store: active_store, 
        triggerAction:'all',
        name: 'active',
        valueField: 'active',
        displayField:'active',
        padding: '2 6 2 7'
    }
]
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `autoLoad: true` from the store, you already fed it the data

Add `queryMode: 'local'` to the combo box since you don't want to send requests to query for data

See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

> If your store is not remote, i.e. it depends only on local data and is loaded up front, you should be sure to set the queryMode to 'local', as this will improve responsiveness for the user.